# PHP - Big Problems When Copying Images from Remote Server

Tags: php, copy

I want to copy pictures, from a remote to my server, but it sometimes copies a wrong image.I tried pretty much every solution, but i will add bellow the easiest one as an example.

The problem is very strange. If I parse a variable from curl that has the value http://www.domain.com/image.jpg, and I download image from this then i get a wrong image.

1)  this do not work ( value of $image is http://www.domain.com/image.jpg)

```
//url of a picture
$image = $result->xpath('image-url');
$image = (string)$image[0];


copy($image, '/patch/image.jpg');
```

2) This works  - when i define the image url directly.

```
//url of a picture pulled by curl
$image = $result->xpath('image-url');
$image = (string)$image[0];


if($image == 'http://www.domain.com/image.jpg') {

 $image = 'http://www.domain.com/image.jpg';
}


copy($image, '/patch/image.jpg');
```

In both cases the value of $image is completely the same, but first one sometimes downloads wrong image, while second one always downloads the right ones.

Can you please help?

```
 I have tried few variation:
 1) $img = file_get_contents('http://placehold.it/150x150');  - WORKS
 2) $img = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/image.jpg');  -WORKS
 3) $img = file_get_contents($image);   where  
 var_dump($image) = string(66) "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg"
 echo $image =   http://www.domain.com/image.jpg Doesn't work.
```

Comment: I doubt they are the same. Do a `var_dump($image)` in the first example and see the actual value of the image

Comment: Make your mind up, which one works and which one doesn't.

Comment: second one always works,first works sometimes.It usuallu pul a wrong image.

Comment: i cant help it, but your use of xpath() and $image[0] looks wrong to me. Who guerantess that the image comming as a result from xpath is the one you want? since you always take the first array element

Comment: @Najzero. The xpatch part is completely ok. I echoed the $image and it is always ok.

Comment: The resulr of vardump: string(66) "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg"

Comment: In my answer I shared the way to copy images from remote server. You just need to integrate it into your code. Noone will did it better than you until we will not see all the code. Think, debug. Don't worry, you will finally find the error. It is just a question of the time.

Comment: post the contents of the $result variable please

Answer (score 3):

This makes no logic at all:

```
if($image == 'http://www.domain.com/image.jpg') {

 $image = 'http://www.domain.com/image.jpg';
}
```

Try this:

```
$img = file_get_contents('http://placehold.it/150x150');
$fh = fopen('path/to/image/new', 'w+');
if (is_resource($fh)) {
    fwrite($fh, $img);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

I do not use `copy()` for such cases.
Better use `file_get_contents()` or `curl`.

Comment: I ask because this doesn't make sense for me as well.  I got ok results only when use this nosense part. I already tried curl and fopen but the results is the same. But i will try again your example.

Comment: I have tried few variation:
1) $img = file_get_contents('http://placehold.it/150x150');  - WORKS
2) $img = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/image.jpg');  -WORKS
3) $img = file_get_contents($image);   where  
var_dump($image) = string(66) "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg"
echo $image =   http://www.domain.com/image.jpg

Doesn't work.

Comment: string(66) "domain.com/image.jpg" - WRONG! HTTP protocol must be specified!

Comment: Try `(string)$image` instead of `$image` : `$img = file_get_contents((string)$image);`

Comment: Try force converting to string anyway.

Comment: I have tried this but i cannot get it to work. $imagebig =  mb_convert_encoding($imagebig, "UTF-8");
$imagebig =  strval($imagebig);

Comment: Oh no no not ths way! I just wanted to know what happens if use `file_get_contents((string)$image);`? Does it work this way?

Comment: No no matter what i do it is the same. Random pictures are pulled from right urls, and there is absolutely no reason for that.

Comment: Debug you code carefully. Make sure that URL's which can not be fetched are valid. At lease, collect them and show to us.

Comment: Well everything works just fine when i specify image url directly.The only problem is value of $image. When i do echo $image i am getting the right value. I suppose if var_dump($image) = string(66) "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg" then $image = "http://www.domain.com/image.jpg" isn't it.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanBurim!  where you wrote fopen('path/to/image/new' ... I thought the 'new' was still the DIR name, not the name of the new file.  Fixed now.  Needs to be ../new.jpg  ...  Cheers